# Trigger dialog show() event from component

Tags: angular

I am trying to open a dialog when an event triggered from UI. I tried with button click in html it's working but I don't know how to open it from Component.

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="cm.show()">ADD</button>
<dialog class="mdl-dialog" #cm="dialog">
    <div class="wpr">
        <span (click)="cm.close()" class="close hairline"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        content...
    </div>
</dialog>
```

**Component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { DialogComponent } from '../../dialog/dialog';

    @Component({
        selector: 'test-app',
        templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
        directives: [
            DialogComponent
        ]
    })

    export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.callCalendar();
    }
    callCalendar() {
        this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            disableResizing: true,
            header: {
                right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                left: 'today prev next '
            },
            eventClick: function (calEvent: any, jsEvent: any, view: any) {
                console.log("calEvent called....", calEvent);
                // here I want to open a popup
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I click on UI it will triggers  **eventClick** function. So, here I want to open a popup window.

help me.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, would you kindly accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child) annotation. This way you get the reference to the component in your template.

```ts
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    @ViewChild(DialogComponent) // or @ViewChild('dialog')
    private _dialogRef: DialogComponent;

    ngOnInit() {
        this._dialogRef.show();
    }
}
```